# Has_secure_password checks validations but not for password reset (doesn't save password but also no error message)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

For a new signup and for an update in user profile, has_secure_password properly checks the validations. This includes the length of the password and checking if the password confirmation matches.

How can I have the same for the password reset? (this used to work but doesn't anymore for some reason)

However, the password reset resource doesn't seem to check these validations. After following the password reset link sent by email, I can fill in a password that is too short and/or a password confirmation that doesn’t match, and then it still redirects as if the resetted password was saved and shows a (flash?) message that the new password has been saved. I can even leave the confirmation password empty. So it doesn't seem to check the validations for a password reset. On the other hand, even though it generated a succes message, it actually doesn’t save the new password (as it shouldn’t since it doesn’t pass validations).

When I would try this for a new signup or when updating my existing profile, then it would generate an error message such as `Password confirmation doesn't match Password` and `Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)`, as it should.

Does anyone know what is wrong about my code so that it doesn't work with the password reset? I have no idea where to look for the cause, since I would expect has_secure_password to automatically manage this. The two user models include:

```
attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true
```

The password reset edit view includes (a second view for the other user type is similar):

```
<%= form_for(@member, url: password_reset_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :email, @member.email %>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.submit "Update password", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

And the password resets controller is:

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :valid_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_expiration,  only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
  end

  def create
    @member = Member.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    @organization = Organization.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @organization
      @organization.create_reset_digest
      @organization.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "An email is sent to you with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    elsif @member
      @member.create_reset_digest
      @member.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:info] = "An email is sent to you with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    if @organization
      render action: "editorg"
    elsif @member
      render action: "editmem"
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def update
    if password_blank?
      flash.now[:danger] = "Password can't be blank"
      if @organization
        render 'editorg'
      elsif @member
        render 'editmem'
      else
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    elsif 
      if @organization
        @organization.update_attributes(passreset_params)
        log_in("organization", @organization)
        flash[:success] = "Your password has been reset."
        redirect_to @organization
      elsif @member
        @member.update_attributes(passreset_params)
        log_in("member", @member)
        flash[:success] = "Your password has been reset."
        redirect_to @member
      end
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end


  private

    def passreset_params
      if @organization
        params.require(:organization).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
      elsif @member
        params.require(:member).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
      end
    end

    # Returns true if password is blank.
    def password_blank?
      if @organization
        params[:organization][:password].blank?
      elsif @member
        params[:member][:password].blank?
      end
    end

    # Before filters

    def get_user
      @member = Member.find_by(email: params[:email])
      @organization = Organization.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end

    # Confirms a valid user.
    def valid_user
      if @organization
        unless (@organization && @organization.activated? && @organization.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
          redirect_to root_url
        end
      elsif @member
        unless (@member && @member.activated? && @member.authenticated?(:reset, params[:id]))
          redirect_to root_url
        end
      else
        flash[:danger] = "Not a valid user."
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    # Checks expiration of reset token.
    def check_expiration
      if @organization
        if @organization.password_reset_expired?
          flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
          redirect_to new_password_reset_url
        end
      elsif @member
        if @member.password_reset_expired?
          flash[:danger] = "Password reset has expired."
          redirect_to new_password_reset_url
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. In the password reset controller, the second half of `def update` needed an additional if-else statement to account for a failure of update. So this means:

```
else 
  if @organization
    if @organization.update_attributes(passreset_params)
      log_in("organization", @organization)
      flash[:success] = "Your password has been reset."
      redirect_to @organization
    else
      render 'editorg'
    end
  elsif @member
    if @member.update_attributes(passreset_params)
      log_in("member", @member)
      flash[:success] = "Your password has been reset."
      redirect_to @member
    else
      render 'editmem'
    end
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "Update failed."
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```